# Codeigniter - Separating two views from ajax response

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I am using Ajax for storing data into database, and I have loaded two views in the controller function. Now, in response I am getting two content of two views. Can anybody tell me how can I separate the two div's?

my ajax code is folows:

```
$.ajax({
        url:base_url+'welcome/add_group_to_archieve',
        type:'post',
        data:data,
        success:function(response){
            $(".group_value").html(response);               
            alert(response);
            get_groups_list();
            $(".archieves_list").html(response);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('ajax failure');
        }

    });
```

controller:

```
public function add_group_to_archieve() {
        $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $archieve_selected = $this->input->post('archieve_selected');
        $this->s_model->insert_as_archieve($archieve_selected);
        $data['get_archieved_groups'] = $this->s_model->get_archieved_groups();
        $data['retrieved_group_values'] = $this->s_model->retrieve_group_post();
        $data['file_id'] = $this->s_model->get_profile_picture($user_id);
        $data['edited_content'] = $this->s_model->get_save($user_id);
        $this->load->view('ajax_response_archieved_groups_list', $data);
        $this->load->view('ajax_response_archieved_groups_select', $data);
    }
```

model:

```
  function get_archieved_groups() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('archieved', 'archieved');
        $data = $this->db->get('groups');

        return $data->result();
    }
```

div1:

```
<div class="archieves clearfix" id="ajax_response_archieved_groups_list">
    <div class="archieves_list">
        <h6>Archieved Group Tags</h6>
        <? //php echo '<pre>'; print_r($get_archieved_groups[0]); echo '</pre>'; exit; ?>
        <ul><?php
        if (isset($get_archieved_groups)) {
            foreach ($get_archieved_groups as $row) {
                ?>
                    <li><?php if (isset($row->group_name)) { ?><?php
                echo $row->group_name;
            }
                ?></li>


                    <?
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

div2:

```
<div class="creating archieves" id="ajax_response_archieved_groups_select1">
    <select id="archieves_select_box">
        <option value="<?php echo "All"; ?>"><?php echo "All"; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($get_archieved_groups as $row) { ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row->group_name; ?>"><?php echo $row->group_name; ?></option>        
        <?php } ?>


    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: how can anybody tell you without solid information? No code or your struggle no answer? Please provide some more informtion.

Comment: Why do you have two time loading view? $this->load->view('ajax_response_archieved_groups_list', $data); $this->load->view('ajax_response_archieved_groups_select', $data); If want to load only one view at a time add some condition before loading the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, just made two separate functions for loading different views and called two different ajax response.
Following is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url:base_url+'welcome/add_group_to_archieve',
        type:'post',
        data:data,
        success:function(response){
            $(".group_value").html(response);               
            alert(response);
            get_groups_list();
            $(".archieves_list").html(response);
            archieved_select();
},
error:function(){
    alert('ajax failure');
}     
});
function archieved_select(){
     $.ajax({
    url:base_url+'welcome/add_group_to_archieve_select',
    type:'post',
    data:data,
    success:function(response){
    $("#ajax_response_archieved_groups_select1").html(response);
},
error:function(){
    alert('ajax failure');
}    
});
```